# Purchase indefinite amount in-app purchase iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Is there a way a make a purchase for an indefinite amount?

In my app, I basically show a video and as the user is watching the video, i start charging it. Say, 0.1 cent per second.

If the user decides to stop it, I charge however $$ for the amount user has watched.

But is this something that is supported in storeKit?

Comment: I hope not. If an app did that to me, I'd be pretty upset.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not supported.

The closest functionality I can imagine would be to sell allotments of video-watching time – say, 1000 seconds for $1 – then charge against the user's stored value as they watch videos. This would be a "consumable product." See the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2) for details.